# Read dbf files with deleted flag in R

Tags: r, dbf, dbase

I am using `foreign::read.dbf` to read a dbase file into R (that works). However, the records in a dbase file can have a **deleted flag**. I my case, these flags are stored in a seperate ".cdx". The flag means the records has been marked for deletion, but not removed from the file. Deletion of these records is usually done by the PACK command in the database, but I would like to know if there is a way to do it in R, as one cannot always control data sources.

Is there a way to skip these deleted records while reading?
If not, is it possible to import this deleted flag and use it for selecting?

Answer (score 0):

Each data record in the DBF file (after you get past the header) is preceded by a one byte field which indicates if the record is NOT deleted (0x20) or that this record is deleted (0x2A).  If you can read this byte and include or throw away each record based on this byte you may have a solution.